# Tightening Garden Hose to Hose Reel

Tags: hose

[image][image]

I have a slight leak between the hose and where it connects with the reel. I hand tightened it as much as I could but it still leaks. Pliers will not fit inside. I removed the reel and tried to tighten the connection from the top but that didn't work either. Any tips on how I can tighten? Thanks.

Comment: looking through that insert a good set of Channel Locks should do the trick to tighten it.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the gasket/oring is still in the hose fitting if not, get another one at your local hardware store.  You could even try some Teflon tape.